# Two sites/Two domains in one server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm starting to manage an Apache web server and I have very little experience. I have two websites with two different domains (a.com, b.com).

A.com files is on the server root folder (`/htdocs`) and I have a `.htaccess` file configured for that domain already.

B.com is on a subfolder inside the server root (`/htdocs/b/`).

Therefore, depending on the "incoming" request domain, I want to somehow change the folder on the server (using `.htaccess` maybe?).

I have been reading some material on this, such as [this tutorial](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/), [Apache guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), this [blog post](http://www.site5.com/blog/apache/htaccess/redirect-to-blog/20090427/), and even this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801914/htaccess-hosting-multiple-domains-on-one-shared-server), but nothing seems to have worked so far.

Changing the `.htaccess` is the correct thing to do? Can I do a mod_rewrite without the user noticing that the folder has been changed (keep it as "b.com" and not "b.com/b")?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if host is b.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?b\.com$ [NC]
# silently forward to folder /b/ if not already /b/
RewriteRule !^b(/|$) /b%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

**PS:** Though it will be better to change your `VistualHost` config and set `/htdocs/b/` as `DocumentRoot` for `b.com` site.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be redirecting to the correct folder! However, it changes back to a.com/b, instead of being b.com. I'm guessing it has something to do with other .htaccess rules in the same file, maybe? Any idea on how to solve this? (Should I post my .htaccess file here?)

About the virtualhost, I have never tried that, I will take a look at that alternative way! Thank you so much!

Comment: I just figured out the VirtualHost and you are right, it is totally the best option! Thank you so much, problem solved! :)