# Good pratice for multiple domains on the same server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have multiple domains going to the same IP / server (I do shared hosting of multiple domains on my own server). I would like :

http://domain1.com/* => `/var/www/domain1/*`

http://domain2.com/* => `/var/www/domain2/*`

Up to now I do it with PHP : all requests are sent to a single PHP file that does the redistribution :

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'domain1') !== false)
      // call the file in /var/www/domain1/*
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'domain2') !== false)
      // call the file in /var/www/domain2/*
```

I can imagine that there exists a "cleaner" solution without PHP, but just `.htaccess` ?

**What is the best pratice for having multiple domains going to the same server? How should I route the requests from multiple domains to the right directory of the server?**

---

*Note : I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801914/htaccess-hosting-multiple-domains-on-one-shared-server) but as there is only 1 upvote, I'm not sure if this is really relevant.*

Comment: apache vhost, nothing to do with php https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: you should be setting up virtual servers in your apache/nginx/<insert web server>.conf if you don't know how try one of these http://alternativeto.net/software/cpanel/

Comment: What should I do if the domains are only a *landing page*  (ie just one HTML page). Should I do multiple VirtualHosts, even for a 1-page website ? Or for such a simple thing, should I do it with just a simple single .htaccess at the root of `/var/www` , and filter with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use VirtualHosts to route certain sites to directories.

Here's the general configuration I use (in `httpd.conf` - there's loads of other info [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

You can also place these directives in different files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<name>.conf` and then do `a2ensite <name>`, if you're on a system that supports that (Debian/Ubuntu IIRC).

Comment: Thanks! just to be sure: having 10 VirtualHosts doesn't imply to have 10 instances of Apache running (and thus increasing the server CPU load) in parallel ?  More generally, does having multiple VirtualHosts increase CPU load ?

Comment: Multiple VirtualHosts increases CPU load very very slightly. But you really won't notice it at least as long as the number of VirtualHosts stays quite low as 10 or maybe 30.

Comment: some servers run thousands of sites this way.

Comment: But, if CPU load is a real issue you probably shouldn't use apache and instead try out some lightweight alternative as nginx. However, if it is not really an issue you should just use apache for now as it gets much more complicated when using nginx or others...

Comment: Thanks @Dagon and @StefanK for your advices. If each domain is just a single-page landing-page, should I do multiple VirtualHosts? Or for such a simple thing, should I just put .htaccess at the root of `/var/www`, and filter with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` ?  (see question's main comments?)

Comment: personally i would still create virtual hosts for each